# class variable was caches in next request when use django-rest-framework renderer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I make use of uwsgi, django and django-rest-framework to develop one application.

I introduced one class variable in renderer class, this variable will be fill as one part of response.

the problem seems likes as following:

```
class xxxRenderer(xxxBase)
    response_pb_msg = obj # it's one instance of protobuf message 

    def render():
        if True:
            self.response_pb_msg.items = []
        else:
            self.response_pb_msg.retCode = 100
            self.response_pb_msg.otherXXXX = xxxx
```

In django logger handler, I access this class variable again like following:

```
xxxRenderer.response_pb_msg.ParseFromString(body)
```

after the first response, this class variable 'response_pb_msg' only has one property "retCode"

**but the second response, it has three properties "retCode", "otherXXXX "  and "items "**

it's strange, the second response contain all content which was exist in the first response.

after a time, I re-wrote this class like following:

```
class xxxBaserender(xxRender)
    def __init__():
        if self.response_pb_msg_cls is not None and isinstance(self.response_pb_msg_cls, GeneratedProtocolMessageType):
            self.response_pb_message = self.response_pb_msg_cls()

class xxxRenderer(xxxBaserender)
    response_pb_msg_cls = msgName # the class of protobuf message
```

theoretically, the second class is ok. I tested, didn't duplicate that question.

**Let's return to where we started**
Every request finisehd, all resoure should be clean. 
but I'm very puzzled with that problem, it seems that class variable not been released in uwsgi progress after response return.

I read “PEP 3333”， didn't get any valuable information.
I think I didn't fully understand class variaable, wsgi and web processing flow in python.

anyone can help me to understand this problem?

thanks vey much.

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you? That modules (including class definitions) are only loaded once in a python interpreter? This has nothing really to do with uwsgi, that just manages the interpreter and reuses it for multiple requests instead of restarting it each time. The same would also occur in a simple multithreaded server. You shouldn't think of class definitions as "resoucres".

Comment: thanks very much, I confound python with PHP.